# Export PDF annotations (highlights and notes)

Tags: javascript

I would like to export my highlights & notes annotations from a PDF. Bt I don't seem to find a free software that can do it. So I was wondering if there is a way I can do it myself using **Javascript**.
FYI I'm running Ubuntu

Comment: Exporting the pdf from where?

Comment: export pdf comments & highlights from the actual document